# How do you get rid of ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration INFO log message

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

When using spring-cloud-config-starter the following message appears on the logs

> INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51f9b0ce] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

I tried

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$$BeanPostProcessorChecker: WARN
    root: WARN
```

and

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: WARN
    root: WARN
```

and

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.BeanPostProcessorChecker: WARN
    root: WARN
```

In `application.yml` in the config server, and in the `bootstrap.yml` but it still appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inner class names need a special handling in the application.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.context.support.[PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker]: WARN
```

See for example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/714

To have these "special characters" in your property key names, you need to take advantage of the map-based binding rules in Spring Boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#map-based-binding